# Child Insurance Policy-if proposer is missing

Tags: insurance

I have taken an insurance policy for my son, which is having premium waiver rider in case of my death or disability...Just wants to know what will happen..if I along with my husband gets missing..

Comment: What country, Missing persons are declared dead based on country guidelines. The policy details ... some of this would be outlined in the policy guidelines

Answer (score 3):

What happens to a minor if the parents are missing, or incapacitated, or deceased should be planned now, and not end up a matter for the courts to decide.

You might need to sit down with a family lawyer as well as a fee based financial planner, to make sure you have addressed all the relevant details.

These details would include where they would live, money, and what the money should be used for.